# How can I send files to test a request endpoint with Rails and RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've been spending my evening trying to figure this out, to no avail. I am running on Rails 7.

​

I am writing requests tests in Rspec to test an endpoint, that attaches pictures to a user.

​

Sending the file from my frontend (React / Javascript), this action controller works :

```
def add_profile_pictures
    puts "\n Params in add_profile_pics"
    p params
    if current_user
      puts "\n current user in"

      # Attach profile pictures
      # if test

      # else

      # end
      current_user.profile_pics.attach(params[:user][:profile_pics])

      render json: { message: 'Pictures added' }, status: :ok
    else
      render json status: :unauthorized
    end
```

And y user properly receives its attached pictures. My model tests work as well.

​

How do I get this controller to work for my Rspec tests?
I've tried:

```
 describe 'POST /users/:id/pictures' do
    context 'with valid params' do
      let(:picture_attributes_valid) do
        {
          profile_pics: [
            ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
              tempfile: File.new(Rails.root.join('db', 'seed_assets', 'maleProfile-1.jpg')),
              filename: 'maleProfile-1.jpg',
              type: 'image/jpeg'
            )
            # fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('db', 'seed_assets', 'maleProfile-1.jpg'),
            # 'image/jpeg')
          ]
        }
      end

      let(:picture_file) do
        fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('db', 'seed_assets', 'maleProfile-1.jpg'),
                            'image/jpeg')
      end

      it 'should accept 1 picture' do
        created_user
        user = User.last
        # post "/users/#{user.id}/pictures", params: { user: picture_attributes_valid }, headers: valid_headers, as: :json
        post "/users/#{user.id}/pictures", params: { user: { profile_pics: picture_file } }, headers: valid_headers,
                                           as: :json
        user.reload(methods: [:profile_pics_urls])
        user.profile_pics.reload
        
        expect(user.profile_pics).to be_attached
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
        expect(user.profile_pics.count).to eq(1)
      end
    end
```

`fixture_file_upload` doesn't do the trick, I tried `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new`  as well.

And my error is always the same:

```
Failures:

  1) /users POST /users/:id/pictures with valid params should accept 1 picture
     Failure/Error: current_user.profile_pics.attach(params[:user][:profile_pics])

     ArgumentError:
       Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<ActionController::Parameters {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "original_filename"=>"maleProfile-1.jpg", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007f1900ad5a78>"} permitted: false>
```

I've tried logging my file params, and how they are received in the controller through the test:

```
checking picture_attributes_valid
{:profile_pics=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f1900ad8098 @tempfile=#<File:.../backend/db/seed_assets/maleProfile-1.jpg>, @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="maleProfile-1.jpg", @headers=nil>]}

checking picture_file
#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x00007f1900ad6770 @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="maleProfile-1.jpg", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/maleProfile-120231129-13559-nne2x2.jpg>>

 Params in add_profile_pics
#<ActionController::Parameters {"user"=>{"profile_pics"=>{"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "original_filename"=>"maleProfile-1.jpg", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007f1900ad5a78>"}}, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"add_profile_pictures", "id"=>"cfa032ae-82d5-40b9-8b24-1c636c015f2c"} permitted: false>
#<ActionController::Parameters {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "original_filename"=>"maleProfile-1.jpg", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007f1900ad5a78>"} permitted: false>
```

Any ideas?

I do not want to change my action in my controller, as it works in my app. I want to adapt my RSpec test to accept the file and add to the user model.

​

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Rack istead? `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("path_to_file")` And could you also add the error message from the request?

Comment: If I use the `fixture_file_upload` you can see that it sends `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` format.
As it is, my controller does not show any error,

Comment: I tried, just to make sure. And it's the same thing. The issue is that it seems it's not receiving the "file", just the `ActionController::Parameters`

Comment: Sorry @TTD the error is the `ArgumentError`seen in the code block.